# is there another phrase entirely that is another way of saying "I have mixed feelings"?

Tags: expressions

With regards to having varying difference of emotional state Ive heard the standard statements "having mixed feelings" and "Im torn " "Unsure of how I feel".... what are some ways of expressing this?

Comment: As Zaphod Beeblebrox might say, "I am of two minds".

Answer (score 1):

To be **ambivalent**:

> having two opposing feelings at the same time, or being uncertain
>   about how you feel:
>
> - *I felt very ambivalent about leaving home.*
> - *He has fairly ambivalent feelings towards his father.*
> - *an ambivalent attitude to exercise*

Source: [dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ambivalent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ambivalent)